How can I obtain the field value in a tab delimited file via PowerShell?
I have a tab delimited file with three fields in each record. I need to obtain the value of the second field so I can parse it to create two new fields at the end of the record. Once I am able to identify the value of the field, I believe I know how to parse that data to create the two fields I need. Any assistance would be appreciated.
At this point I have the following that displays each record in the file successfully.
# Get contents of file and add file date and account number to end of line in file
$f = Get-Content -Path "$stat_path\$file_prefix$stat_date$file_extension"

ForEach ($line in $f) {
    $record = $line.split("'t")
    #$member_nbr[1] | Out-Host
    #$PDF_file_name[2] | Out-Host
    $record | Out-Host
}


Dont use Get-Content, treat your data for what it is, a TSV so use Import-Csv -Delimiter "`t"


As Santiago notes, it's best to parse your TSV (tab-separated values) data file as such, by passing your file to Import-Csv with -Delimiter "`t" (rather than relying on brittle plain-text parsing); this allows you to use OOP techniques to process each row:
Import-Csv -Delimiter "`t" "$stat_path\$file_prefix$stat_date$file_extension" |
  ForEach-Object {
    # Get the value of the second field.
    $secondField =  @($_.psobject.Properties)[1].Value
    # Add two new fields (adjust the field names and derive their values
    # from $secondField as needed),
    # and output the modified object (-PassThru).
    $_ | Add-Member -PassThru -NotePropertyMembers ([ordered] @{
      FirstNewField = 'new 1'
      SecondNewField = 'new 2'
    })
  }


You can pipe the result to Export-Csv with -Delimiter "`t" to save back to a TSV file.

If you want to save back to the same file, enclose the Import-Csv call in (...), to ensure that its content is read in full up front (make a backup copy first, to be safe).

The intrinsic psobject property is used to reflect on the properties of each data row that Import-Csv parses into an object, and via @(...), the array-subexpression operator, the second ([1]) property value (.Value) is extracted.

Add-Member is then used to add two additional properties to the object at hand, with -PassThru requesting that the modified object be output afterwards.

Note the use of [ordered] @{ ... } - of syntactic necessity enclosed in (...) to ensure that is recognized as a command argument - in order to create an ordered hashtable, so that the entries become properties of the target object in definition order (which a regular hashtable @{ ... } wouldn't ensure).



